# Graph convolutions in Keras

Tags: graph, keras, neural-network

How can we implement graph convolutions in Keras?
Ideally in the form of a layer accepting 2 inputs - the set (as time-sequence) of nodes and (same time dimension length) set of integer indexes (into the time dimension) of each node's neighbours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we would be able to gather items into the style and shape of Conv layers, we could use normal convolutions.
The gather can be done using this Keras layer which uses tensorflow's gather.

```
class GatherFromIndices(Layer):
    """
    To have a graph convolution (over a fixed/fixed degree kernel) from a given sequence of nodes, we need to gather
    the data of each node's neighbours before running a simple Conv1D/conv2D,
     that would be effectively a defined convolution (or even TimeDistributed(Dense()) can be used - only
     based on data format we would output).
    This layer should do exactly that.

    Does not support non integer values, values lesser than 0 zre automatically masked.
    """
    def __init__(self, mask_value=0, include_self=True, flatten_indices_features=False, **kwargs):
        Layer.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.mask_value = mask_value
        self.include_self = include_self
        self.flatten_indices_features = flatten_indices_features

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'mask_value': self.mask_value,
                  'include_self': self.include_self,
                  'flatten_indices_features': self.flatten_indices_features,
                  }
        base_config = super(GatherFromIndices, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    #def build(self, input_shape):
        #self.built = True

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        inp_shape, inds_shape = input_shape
        indices = inds_shape[-1]
        if self.include_self:
            indices += 1
        features = inp_shape[-1]
        if self.flatten_indices_features:
            return tuple(list(inds_shape[:-1]) + [indices * features])
        else:
            return tuple(list(inds_shape[:-1]) + [indices, features])

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        inp, inds = inputs
        # assumes input in the shape of (inp=[...,batches, sequence_len, features],
        #  inds = [...,batches,sequence_ind_len, neighbours]... indexing into inp)
        # for output we want to get  [...,batches,sequence_ind_len, indices,features]

        assert_shapes = tf.Assert(tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(tf.shape(inp)[:-2], tf.shape(inds)[:-2])), [inp])
        assert_positive_ins_shape = tf.Assert(tf.reduce_all(tf.greater(tf.shape(inds), 0)), [inds])
        # the shapes need to be the same (with the exception of the last dimension)
        with tf.control_dependencies([assert_shapes, assert_positive_ins_shape]):
            inp_shape = tf.shape(inp)
            inds_shape = tf.shape(inds)

            features_dim = -1
            # ^^ todo for future variablility of the last dimension, because maybe can be made to take not the last
            # dimension as features, but something else.

            inp_p = tf.reshape(inp, [-1, inp_shape[features_dim]])
            ins_p = tf.reshape(inds, [-1, inds_shape[features_dim]])

            # we have lost the batchdimension by reshaping, so we save it by adding the size to the respective indexes
            # we do it because we use the gather_nd as nonbatched (so we do not need to provide batch indices)
            resized_range = tf.range(tf.shape(ins_p)[0])
            different_seqs_ids_float = tf.scalar_mul(1.0 / tf.to_float(inds_shape[-2]), tf.to_float(resized_range))
            different_seqs_ids = tf.to_int32(tf.floor(different_seqs_ids_float))
            different_seqs_ids_packed = tf.scalar_mul(inp_shape[-2], different_seqs_ids)
            thseq = tf.expand_dims(different_seqs_ids_packed, -1)

            # in case there are negative indices, make them all be equal to -1
            #  and add masking value to the ending of inp_p - that way, everything that should be masked
            #  will get the masking value as features.
            mask = tf.greater_equal(ins_p, 0)  # extract where minuses are, because the will all default to default value
            # .. before the mod operation, if provided greater id numbers, to wrap correctly small sequences
            offset_ins_p = tf.mod(ins_p, inp_shape[-2]) + thseq  # broadcast to ins_p
            minus_1 = tf.scalar_mul(tf.shape(inp_p)[0], tf.ones_like(mask, dtype=tf.int32))
            '''
            On GPU, if we use index = -1 anywhere it would throw a warning:
            OP_REQUIRES failed at gather_nd_op.cc:50 : Invalid argument: 
            flat indices = [-1] does not index into param.
            Which is a warning, that there are -1s. We are using that as feature and know about that.
            '''
            offset_ins_p = tf.where(mask, offset_ins_p, minus_1)
            # also possible to do something like  tf.multiply(offset_ins_p, mask) + tf.scalar_mul(-1, mask)
            mask_value_last = tf.zeros((inp_shape[-1],))
            if self.mask_value != 0:
                mask_value_last += tf.constant(self.mask_value)  # broadcasting if needed
            inp_p = tf.concat([inp_p, tf.expand_dims(mask_value_last, 0)], axis=0)

            # expand dims so that it would slice n times instead having slice of length n indices
            neighb_p = tf.gather_nd(inp_p, tf.expand_dims(offset_ins_p, -1))  # [-1,indices, features]

            out_shape = tf.concat([inds_shape, inp_shape[features_dim:]], axis=-1)
            neighb = tf.reshape(neighb_p, out_shape)
            # ^^ [...,batches,sequence_len, indices,features]

            if self.include_self: # if is set, add self at the 0th position
                self_originals = tf.expand_dims(inp, axis=features_dim-1)
                # ^^ [...,batches,sequence_len, 1, features]
                neighb = tf.concat([neighb, self_originals], axis=features_dim-1)

            if self.flatten_indices_features:
                neighb = tf.reshape(neighb, tf.concat([inds_shape[:-1], [-1]], axis=-1))

            return neighb
```

With a debuggable interactive test:

```
def allow_tf_debug(func):
    """
    Decorator for tests that use tensorflow, to make them more breakpoint-friendly, i.e. to be able to call .eval()
    on tensors immediately.
    """
    def interactive_wrapper():
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        ret = func()
        sess.close()
        return ret
    return interactive_wrapper


@allow_tf_debug
def test_gather_from_indices():
    gat = GatherFromIndices(include_self=False, flatten_indices_features=False)
    # test for include_self=True is not included
    # test for flatten_indices_features not included

    seq = [  # batch of sequences
        # sequences of 2d features
        [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]],
        [[10, 1], [11, 2], [12, 3], [13, 4], [14, 5], [15, 6], [16, 7], [17, 8]]
        ]

    ids = [  # batch of sequences
        # sequences of 3 ids of each item in sequence
        [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 0], [7, 0, -1]]
        # minus one should mean masking
        ]

    def compute_assert_2ways_gathers(seq, ids):
        seq = np.array(seq, dtype=np.float32)
        ids = np.array(ids, dtype=np.int32)
        # intended_look
        result_np = None
        if len(ids.shape) == 3:  # classical batches
            result_np = np.empty(list(ids.shape) + [seq.shape[-1]])
            for b, seq_in_batch in enumerate(ids):
                for i, sid in enumerate(seq_in_batch):
                    for c, copyid in enumerate(sid):
                        assert ids[b,i,c] == copyid
                        if ids[b,i,c] < 0:
                            result_np[b, i, c, :] = 0
                        else:
                            result_np[b, i, c, :] = seq[b, ids[b,i,c], :]
        elif len(ids.shape) == 4:  # some other batching format...
            result_np = np.empty(list(ids.shape) + [seq.shape[-1]])
            for mb, mseq_in_batch in enumerate(ids):
                for b, seq_in_batch in enumerate(mseq_in_batch):
                    for i, sid in enumerate(seq_in_batch):
                        for c, copyid in enumerate(sid):
                            assert ids[mb, b, i, c] == copyid
                            if ids[mb, b, i, c] < 0:
                                result_np[mb, b, i, c, :] = 0
                            else:
                                result_np[mb, b, i, c, :] = seq[mb, b, ids[mb, b, i, c], :]

        output_shape_kerascomputed = gat.compute_output_shape([seq.shape, ids.shape])
        assert isinstance(output_shape_kerascomputed, tuple)
        assert list(output_shape_kerascomputed) == list(result_np.shape)
        #with tf.get_default_session() as sess:
        sess = tf.get_default_session()
        gat.build(seq.shape)
        result = gat.call([tf.constant(seq), tf.constant(ids)])
        tf_result = sess.run(result)

        assert list(tf_result.shape) == list(output_shape_kerascomputed)
        assert np.all(np.equal(tf_result, result_np))

    compute_assert_2ways_gathers(seq, ids)
    compute_assert_2ways_gathers(seq * 5, ids * 5)
    compute_assert_2ways_gathers([seq] * 3, [ids] * 3)
```

And usage example for 5 neighbours per node:

```
fields_input = Input(shape=(None, 10, name='nodedata')
neighbours_ids_input = Input(shape=(None, 5), name='nodes_neighbours_ids', dtype='int32')

fields_input_with_neighbours = GatherFromIndices(mask_value=0,
                                                 include_self=True, flatten_indices_features=True)\
    ([fields_input, neighbours_ids_input])

fields = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, padding='same',
                activation='relu')(fields_input_with_neighbours)  #  data_format="channels_last"
```